# Check if a new version of go based binary is available using go get

Tags: go, installation, upgrade

I am a little bit new to Go, specifically `go get` mechanism to download single binaries (CLI apps). Some cool projects in github allow you to download cli apps using `go get`. How can I check that binary that I installed is outdated? I am looking for something like debian based `apt update` that checks for newest package versions without installing them.

As an example. Let's say that I installed lazygit using `go get github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit`. And after a while a new version was released in github . Is it possible to check new version of binary using `go get`?

Comment: `go get` doesn't download binaries at all. It downloads source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the help and found the -u flag.  Use `go get -u github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit` to update the tool.

None of this is speicific to the GitHub.

Comment: `go get -u` is not specific to Github in any way.